# Visual Studios UWP save DatePicker into XML-File

Tags: c#, uwp, datepicker

I am new to Visual Studio and currently im trying to save an DatePicker into an XML-File.
I already saved an TextBox into an XML File but I dont know how to convert an DatePicker into an String or an Integer.

```cs
FileStream fs = new FileStream("", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
KalenderClass kc = new KalenderClass();
kc.Termin = TerminTextBlock.Text;
```

I hope you can help me out.

Comment: The [DatePicker.SelectedDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datepicker.selecteddate?view=winrt-18362) property is the value of the selected Date which type is DateTimeOffset, you can use `DatePicker1.SelectedDate.ToString();` to convert the DatePicker to a String type and then save it into xml like saving the TextBox. If you try this, can it work? If it can't, can you show more details about your expected behavior and unexpected behavior?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`DatePicker.Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datepicker.date?view=winrt-18362) property to retrieve the date picked by the user.

You would then use `kc.Termin = TerminDatePicker.Date;` to save it into a variable of type [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netcore-3.1), and use for example [`DateTimeOffset.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tostring?view=netcore-3.1)  to format it according to your needs into a save file.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But It didnt helped me out. 
I have an DatePicker named DatePicker1 and an class for my calendar with the variables I want to safe in the XML File but sadly I still dont know how to safe the selected Date in the XML File. Hopefully you can help me.